# Passing JSON into a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I get the feeling this is a simple fix, but I can't for the life of me find the error.  I keep getting undefined values when I run this script which is checking an array in a JSON file for boolean data.  I put it all into a fiddle.  Scroll to the bottom of the JS section.  Here's the code for those who don't want to switch tabs.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/x4zV7/)

```
$.ajax({
url: "/echo/json/",
data: data,
type: "POST",
success: function (response) {

    //Loop Start
    for (var fund in response.fundClass){
        console.log(fund.class);
        if(fund.xbrl == false){
            $(fund.class + " .xbrl").addClass(".hide");
        }

        if(fund.prospSum == false){
            $(fund.class + " .prospSum").addClass(".hide");
        }            
    }
    //Loop End

   }
});
```

Comment: When you use `for..in`, you are getting the *keys* not the values.  `console.log(response.fundClass[fund].class);`  Though, since `response.fundClass` is an *array*, I'd suggest *not* using `for..in`.  Just use a "normal" `for(var i = 0; i < response.fundClass.length; i++)` loop.

Comment: A sidenote: Do not use `class` as identifier its reserved

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're trating the "response.fundClass" as an Object, while it's an Array.

[Your fiddle updated](http://jsfiddle.net/x4zV7/1/)

```
for (var i = 0; i < response.fundClass.length; i++) { // looping the Array
    var fund = response.fundClass[i]; // get the object from the Array
    console.log(fund.class);
    if (fund.xbrl == false) {
        $(fund.class + " .xbrl").addClass(".hide");
    }

    if (fund.prospSum == false) {
        $(fund.class + " .prospSum").addClass(".hide");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I didn't realize my `for...in` would be returning keys and not values.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `response.fundClass` is an array. So `for var in` is just giving keys, try the usual for loop rather which is the clear way to do it,

```
for (var i =0 ; i < response.fundClass.length; i++){
    var fund = response.fundClass[i];
    console.log(fund.class);
    if(fund.xbrl == false){
        $(fund.class + " .xbrl").addClass(".hide");
    }

    if(fund.prospSum == false){
        $(fund.class + " .prospSum").addClass(".hide");
    }            
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: `for..in` will *always* give keys.  Doesn't matter if it's an array or an object.

Comment: Definitely, agreed, found the flaw. Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

When you use a `for..in` loop, you are getting the *keys* not the values.  `fund` will be the key of the array, not its value.

```
for (var key in response.fundClass){
    var fund = response.fundClass[key];
    console.log(fund['class']);
}
```

Though, since `response.fundClass` is an array, you *shouldn't* use `for..in`.  Just use a "normal" `for` loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < response.fundClass.length; i++){
    var fund = response.fundClass[i];
    console.log(fund['class']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to a traditional `for(;;)` loop (which is the appropriate traditional method of array enumeration), is to use [`Arrays.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) (shims are widely available). `forEach` will enumerate all the items in an array<sup>1</sup>:

```
response.fundClass.forEach(function (fund) {
  // Invoked once per each item, with fund being the value of the item.

  // This is nice for several reasons, warranted or not here:
  //  1. No explicit lookup by key/index or "extra" variables
  //  2. Each loop is it's own execution context
});
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Only items with *assigned* values are enumerated, but this is a non-issue for arrays restored from JSON.